# Can I create a business object (dll) based on objects from SOAP web service?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a business object layer(dll) in my Web API application.

However the majority of the classes in this layer would be obtained from 3rd party SOAP web service.

How can I create these objects so that I can expose them to my other layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you should map the DataLayer objects to your Business Layer objects. I prefer to return Business objects from the data layer, so that mapping happens there, that way Business Layer does not know anything about Data Layer apart from contract and DL can be later switched easily.

As for the ways of doing it, you can either map it manually, or you can use an automatic mapper (e.g. [EmitMapper](https://emitmapper.codeplex.com/) is a really fast one that generates IL on the fly, so it is almost as fast as manual).